# Django: How to customize the admin form for specific model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views

First of all I apologize the question title can be unrelated to my query. I am also confused what I want to do because I am less familiar with django.

I want to create simple comment system. The requirement is clear that user can post comment with multiple images.Every comment should have reply. so I created following models.

```
#comment table 
class Comments(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True) // for comment reply
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'comments'


#images table
class CommentImages(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comments)
    image = models.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'comments_images'
```

I have query about admin side how can i manage these things?

I want to show images list when admin view the specific comment.

Admin can view replies of specific comment.

Here i draw the example.
[image]

So I dont want to ask about coding. I want to know what techniques will be used to change the admin view. I am using admin panel for others models too so I want to change the specific model view.

How can I get these things? Thank you

Comment: Use inline model admin objects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects and customize the image form. The image field widget should  begin with an img tag displaying the image.

Answer (score -1):

So, to make images render as images write custom widget:

```
class PhotoWidget(ClearableFileInput):
    template_with_initial = '<p class="file-upload"><span class="clearable-file-input">%(input)s %(clear_template)s<br />' \
                            '%(initial)s</p>'

    template_with_clear = '<span class="clearable-file-input">%(clear)s <label for="%(clear_checkbox_id)s">' \
                          '%(clear_checkbox_label)s</label></span>'
    # this is the most important line
    url_markup_template = '<img src="{0}" width="300"/>'
```

Now create some form:

```
class CommentImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
     model = CommentImages
     widgets = {'image': PhotoWidget()}
```

Finally, admin:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = CommentImagesForm
  add_form = CommentImagesForm
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: yes image field. I have updated. I want to show images list in comment form. I am not going to add Commend Image model in admin.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: I got one thing that override the admin form for specific app. But I did not implement yet. I am searching for better solution.